# What does 'share squat' mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, negation, slang

I came across the sentence in a comment from [this news story](https://www.yahoo.com/news/m/1ba288f6-e657-334f-9ec5-6e14eaa72a02/investigators-believe-las.html).

> The investigators are **sharing squat**. But I bet they know a whole a lot.

What does 'sharing squat' mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Squat" is slang for "absolutely nothing." It's presumably a euphemism for "shit." It's commonly heard in the expression "doesn't know squat," meaning "doesn't know anything [about this issue]."

"Doesn't know shit" is equally or more common, and means the same thing more emphatically. (And is vulgar, obviously.)

Comment: It's short for *diddly-squat*, about which [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/diddly-squat) says, "probably from US slang doodle ‘excrement’ + squat in the sense ‘defecate’."

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Somehow it's been so long since I heard "diddly-squat" that it didn't come to mind.